# Is it appropriate to ask a question about a specific user?

Tags: discussion, specific-user

I hope I am kosher in asking this, but this user https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6179/did seems to have been inactive for a long time. I am disappointed because they were very helpful in their answers and comments. They are within the top 15 reputation users on the site so I am surprised by their extended absence. Is it appropriate to ask why they are no longer active on the site?

Comment: on meta. not on main.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee That is why I asked this question on meta.

Comment: You should probably clarify whether you are asking the question in the title or the question in the body. (The title sounds to me like: "Would a question about a specific user be on-topic on meta?" However, the body seems more like: "What happen to the user Did?")

Comment: The only case that I have seen on meta which mentions a (very) specific user in the title is this: [The unilateral removal of comments by Jeff Atwood](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1990/9464).

Comment: See also: [Can/do moderators contact inactive users to try to lure them back?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13004/9464)

Comment: @MartinSleziak My question is indeed "What happened to the user Did?" However, I am trying to be more tactful and ask if the question is kosher, instead of assuming that it was in the first place.

Comment: I am very happy if Didier Piau never comes back. No loss. Andre Nicolas, on the other hand, would be good to have back.

Answer (score 19):

No. It is entirely inappropriate to ask questions whose answers are speculations regarding a particular user.

Users who become inactive have their own reasons for doing so, and it is purely up to their discretion whether or not to share it with the rest of us.

Comment: I don't disagree with you, but it is frustrating to see such an active contributor to the community go. I suppose this should be be left at that, then.

Comment: Yes. Life can be very frustrating sometimes.

Comment: Yes. But whenever someone has an idea what is going on, he/she may also want to share his knowledge with the community. It is only possible over a Meta question. Nobody knows even if this person is alive..

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören: Asking "Why is user X not here?" is not the same as "User X has asked me to say bla bla bla".